# The field is never used - Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, .net

I have problem with warning: "Warning   CS0169  The field 'DBConnection.form2' is never used"

I tried add #pragma warning disable 0169 but it didn't work.

Here is sample of my code:

```
#pragma warning disable 0169
    public static DBConnection Instance()
    {
        if (_instance == null)
        {
            _instance = new DBConnection();
        }
        return _instance;
    }
#pragma warning restore 0169
```

And form2 is looking like this:

```
    #pragma warning disable 0169
    public DBConnection mysqlCon { get; set; }
    #pragma warning restore 0169
```

I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: Do you want to fix it or hide it? Because your real problem is that you're declaring unused vars...

Comment: You have a field name `form2` inside `DbConnection` and you aren't using it

Comment: And also https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/127036/how-to-treat-the-field-is-never-used-warnings

Answer (score 3):

Adding a `pragma` to prevent warning from appearing is just nonsense if you can just fix the actual problem.

So remove the `pragma` and remove the `form2` field in class `DbConnection`. It is not used and it has no use whatsoever.